# Get currentViewController of View Controller in UITabBarController in UINavigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I would like to know how I can find the current view controller if I have a `UITabBarController` and within that TabBarController I have 4 different `UINavigationController`s and then that NavigationController obviously has the stack of view controllers. In my app delegate I am trying to find out this information so that I can stop an in-app push notification from appearing. So I am looking to do something like:

```
if (self.currentViewController != self.chatViewController) {
   //Show the notification everywhere else except here(here being self.chatViewController)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
    UITabBarController *tabBarControler = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navController = [[tabBarControler viewControllers] objectAtIndex:<selected_index>];
    NSArray *navViewControllers = [navController viewControllers];
```

You can check for the present viewController like this.

```
if (navController.topViewController != self.chatViewController) {
 //Show the notification every else except here(here being self.chatViewController)
}
```

**Edit by @kylecman**

What I ended up doing was using the tabbarcontroller and navigation controller instances and not using the array(have not found the need for that)

and then I prepared an IF statement for the viewController's class

```
if (![navController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[ChatView class]] && ![navController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[MessagesViewController class]]) {
```

Comment: I do like this answer. Do you mind accepting my edits when make them because I got it to work with a piece of your code?